# Installed and Uninstalled Java 8 on OSX 10.9.2, Installed Java 7 and Java Control Panel still references Java 8, can't change JNLP security settings

Tags: java, macos

So the title pretty much lays out the problem. I installed Java 8 on OSX 10.9.2, then removed it following the procedure documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

Installed Java 7 and everything is fine except for the Java Control Panel which still thinks Java 8 is installed. Upshot is JNLP files won't load because of security settings which can't be changed in Java Control Panel that is pointing to a nonexistent Java 8 install.

Has anyone figured out how to get the Java Control Panel to point to a new JDK install?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to remove the JDK 8 variant of the JavaApplet plugin and reinstall java 7. The problem is that older versions won't overwrite newer versions - http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml I had the same problem after installing the preview of java 8

Answer (score 2):

I have done the same thing (uninstalling JDK 8 and installing JDK 7) and I find the documentation not sufficient. You should remove the following directories

- /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk***
- /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
- /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane

Then reinstall JDK 7 with the dmg file you downloaded from Oracle.